# Bootstrap dropdown menu increase width following by ul/li

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a Bootstrap dropdown menu increase the width following by ul/li.

This is how it looks like with `width: auto`:

[image: width: auto]

If I manually changed to `width: 300px` instead of `auto` this is how it looks like (this is the result that I want):

[image: width: 300px]

What i have tried is to create a `<div>` and I still get the same result.

The full code:

```
<!--menu-->
<div class="nav-full-width">
    <div class="container wrapper-nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="_desktop_top_menu" class="menu js-top-menu hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <ul id="top-menu" class="top-menu" data-depth="0">
                    {% for category in categories %}
                        {% if category.children %}
                            <li class="maintitle">
                                <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
                                <span class="pull-xs-right hidden-md hidden-lg">
                                    <span data-target="#top_sub_menu_4248" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler collapse-icons" style="width:auto !important;">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down add"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-up remove"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <div id="top_sub_menu_4248" class="dropdown-menu popover sub-menu collapse">
                                    {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled childs_1 category_dropdownmenu  multiple-dropdown-menu " data-depth="1">
                                            {% for child in children %}
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a>
                                                </li>

                                                {% if child.children %}
                                                   
                                                        {% for children in child.children %}
                                                        <ul data-depth="2">
                                                            <li><a href="{{ children.href }}" style="float: left;">{{ children.name }}</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-icon" class="menu-icon hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>   
            <div id="_mobile_cart"></div>
            <div id="_mobile_user_info"></div>
            <div id="_mobile_seach_widget"></div>
            <div id="_mobile_link_menu"></div>
            <div id="_desktop_seach_widget">
                <div id="search_widget" class="search-widget">
                    <div class="search-logo"></div>
                    <form>
                        <div id="search" class="input-group">
                            <input id="ajax-search-text" type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search our category" class="form-control input-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="ajax-search-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my full codes for the navigation menu.

here is the css:

```
#_desktop_top_menu #top-menu>li .sub-menu {
    top: 70%;
    left: 0;
    border: none;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 18;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between both screenshots? What's the difference. Maybe something minute that I must have overlooked?

Comment: @WahabShah here is the difference between `width:auto;` and `width:300px;` https://prnt.sc/1tf827e

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), prefferred with a code snippet. One cannot reproduce your result since the `categories`, `category.children` and so on are not known.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left` from the inline `style` attribute in your line 46:

```
   42 | {% if child.children %}
   43 |     
   44 |         {% for children in child.children %}
   45 |         <ul data-depth="2">
-> 46 |             <li><a href="{{ children.href }}" style="float: left;">{{ children.name }}</a></li>
   47 |         </ul>
   48 |         {% endfor %}
   49 | {% endif %}
```

Personally I try to never use `float`. In my opinion there are just a few cases where `float` is useful. In nearly all layouts I think `float` just destroys the layout completely and causes some weird looking behaviour that is mostly unexpected.